# Cannot run two @Input SubscribleChannels in spring-boot app

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm developing a spring cloud kafka app with kafka streams binder. I have two @Input and one @Output as the following:

```
internal interface OfferChannel {

        companion object {
            const val CREATE_OFFER = "create-offer"
            const val CREATE_OFFER_COUNTER = "create-offer-counter"
            const val OFFER_CREATED = "offer-created"
        }

        @Input(OFFER_CREATED)
        fun offerCreatedChannel(): SubscribableChannel

        @Input(CREATE_OFFER_COUNTER)
        fun createOfferAdminChannel(): SubscribableChannel

        @Output(CREATE_OFFER)
        fun createOfferChannel(): MessageChannel

    }
```

During application startup I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while starting consumer: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:455)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:99)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:144)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleConsumerBinding$0(BindingService.java:171)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one LastSubscriberMessageHandler is allowed
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderErrorChannel.subscribe(BinderErrorChannel.java:44)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.registerErrorInfrastructure(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:704)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.registerErrorInfrastructure(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:627)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:578)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:135)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:402)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Additionally, if I remove one of the @Input declarations the application starts successfully. Any suggestions what it going wrong here ?

Comment: You may want to post your application somewhere on github (so we can look). Something is missing  as it is perfectly fine to have multiple input bindings

Answer (score 2):

Something is related to the version of the libraries.
For example my task was to switch to 2.4 kafka client with `org.springframework.boot` version `2.2.3.RELEASE`. Firstly I updated to the latest `2.2.10.RELEASE` version, you would say it's not a big deal since it's minor version change, well it appears that `2.2.10.RELEASE` caused this bug and I had to revert it to `2.2.9.RELEASE`.
Next step for my kafka version increase was to follow this tutorial:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#update-deps

So I set `implementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.4.9.RELEASE"`, well guess what? `2.4.9.RELEASE` also caused the same problem, so I downgraded it to `2.4.8.RELEASE`.

My working config (not using latest minor versions):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.9.RELEASE'
}

ext {
    springKafkaVersion = '2.4.8.RELEASE'
    kafkaVersion = '2.4.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:$springKafkaVersion"

    implementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:$kafkaVersion"
    implementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:$kafkaVersion"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:$springKafkaVersion"
    testImplementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:$kafkaVersion:test"
}
```

So the suggestion is to look at your library versions and try to upgrade/downgrade accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error when updating spring boot version from 2.2.9 to 2.2.10, current work around is to use the old version. You can check your spring boot version and have a try